# Make CSS navigation bar 'responsive' so whatever the screen size the li elements scale

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

This is a website which has loads of List items. With this code, when I resize the browser, all the other elements scale but the navigation bar and all the list items do not and it looks odd.

Here is the css:

```
.top-nav{

display:inline-block;

}
.top-nav ul li{

display:inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li a{

font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
color: #f8abbe;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 45px 25px;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: normal;
transition: 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;

}


.top-nav li.active> a, .top-nav li> a:hover {
background: #f8abbe;
color:#fff;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="wrap">

        <div class="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Prices & Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Press</a></li>
                 <li><a href="training.html">Makeup Studio <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the horizontal navigation bar more responsive and scale it better. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried media queries and/or elastic-design?

Comment: @Dai No I haven't... I am relatively new too CSS so I had no idea what was wrong. How would I go about implementing this into the code? Thanks!

Comment: @HaziqHussain Google it. There are loads of great options simply by searching "Responsive Navigation Bar". Try something, then come back here when you get stuck.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Hi, I did google that exact term and tried some possible fixes... however it doesn't seem to affect the bar at all. I am puzzled so that is why I have seeked help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution was taken directly from the first result on Google (when searching for "Responsive Navigation Bar")

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.top-nav{

display:inline-block;

}
.top-nav ul li{

display:inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li a{

font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
color: #f8abbe;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 45px 25px;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: normal;
transition: 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;

}

.top-nav li.active> a, .top-nav li> a:hover {
background: #f8abbe;
color:#fff;
} 
 
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

 /* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="top-nav">
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Prices & Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Press</a></li>
                 <li><a href="training.html">Makeup Studio <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, but you have to use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to make any of them work.

In order to keep this almost completely CSS, you can follow something [like this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qLu0dba).

```css
wrap{
  overflow:hidden;
}

top-nav{

display:inline-block;

}
.top-nav ul li{

display:inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li a{

font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
color: #f8abbe;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 45px 25px;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: normal;
transition: 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;

}
.top-nav li.active> a, .top-nav li> a:hover {
background: #f8abbe;
color:#fff;
}

/* here is the meat of your CSS changes */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  
    .top-nav{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      
    }
    .wrap:before{
      content:""; // you can add a carat here if you want, but additional styling may be necessary
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      color: #000;
      margin: 1em 0;
      right:0;
      z-index  : 1;
      background-image : linear-gradient(to right, 
                    rgba(243,245,246, 0), 
                    rgba(243,245,246, 1) 60%);
      width    : 80px; //adjust so that the fade can be seen on the last menu item visible
      height   : 100%;
    }
    
    .top-nav ul{
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 1050px; // needs to be wide enough that all emnu items can o
                     // be stacked horizontally insode the container.
                     // You may want to make it a little wider if you
                     // increase the fade width
      height: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="wrap" id="nav-wrap">

        <div class="top-nav" id="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Prices & Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html">Press</a></li>
                 <li><a href="training.html">Makeup Studio <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The menu ul is made into a block element and the container is set to hide any overflow.  The fade on the right gives a visual hint that there are more menu items to see.  This is simple and 100% CSS, though perhaps not what you're looking for.

The javascript included there, ideally, will adjust the div so that the horizontal scroll bar on that div is invisible.  Most modern browsers handle that so that scrollbars a re more elegant than they used to be, but some of your users may be stuck on Windows 7 or something.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('nav-wrap');
var child = document.getElementById('top-nav');
child.style.paddingBottom = child.offsetWidth - child.clientWidth + "px";
```

If you're looking more for a menu that collapses into a stack and opens/closes on click, you will have to use javascript.  There aren't any click pseudoselectors in CSS, and using hover alone for a collapsible menu means anyone on a mobile device will be unable to see your menu.